Puppeteer - pass variable to selector
new to puppeteer and having trouble understanding how I can pass a variable to the browser inside the querySelector
I've got something to that goes and queries number of active users and returns the value
    const usedLicenses = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > strong').textContent;
  });

If usedLicenses is not 0, I then wish to loop from 1 to whatever the value is to return some further info using this selector
Ignoring the loop  requirement for a minute, it seems like I need something like this but how do I use the variable properly inside the selector?
 const activeUsers = await page.evaluate(({usedLicenses}) => {
    return document.querySelector('#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(usedLicenses) > div.title > strong').textContent;
   },{usedLicenses});

Thanks

Is usedLicenses an object? Why do you use { } around the variable?

It's best to show your page and expected result. This selector is very brittle and poor practice--there's almost never any reason to use nth-child, so this is probably an XY problem. You should be able to scrape all of those lis by simply using page.$$eval and removing the usedLicences variable, which will return an array. There's likely no need to query a separate element to find a length--that's implicit.

Please, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

In Puppeteer, when you're passing a variable into the page.evaluate() function, you need to ensure that the variable is correctly referenced within the function. Since you're passing usedLicenses as an argument to evaluate(), you can access it inside the evaluate function directly by referencing it within the function's scope.
Here’s how you can pass the usedLicenses variable and use it inside the querySelector:
const usedLicenses = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelector('#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > strong').textContent;
});

// Convert the value of usedLicenses to an integer if it's a string
const numLicenses = parseInt(usedLicenses, 10);

const activeUsers = await page.evaluate(({numLicenses}) => {
  // Use numLicenses directly in the selector
  return document.querySelector(`#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(${numLicenses}) > div.title > strong`).textContent;
}, {numLicenses});

console.log(activeUsers);

